# Referencing a 3rd Party class library within a SQL Clr Class

Tags: .net, sql-server, clr

I am creating a SQL CLR assembly that needs to use a Third Party assembly inside it. The trouble is I cannot reference this assembly as only ones already deployed to SQL or other SQL project references are allowed.

Is it possible to use 3rd party assemblies in a SQL CLR assembly and if so how?

Thanks in advance.